# What is the difference between Jest-vue and Vue-jest?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I am studying unit testing for quasar framework now.
But I have not clear about vue-jest and jest-vue.
Please help me what the difference is? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These packages are from the same author. jest-vue was deprecated in favour of vue-jest.

As [the description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-vue) states,

> DEPRECATED
>
> this package has been renamed to vue-jest

Since it's older, jest-vue may not have all features of vue-jest.